# Absolute and conditional convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(x-1)^n}{2^n(3n-1)}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2n -1}(\frac{x+2}{x-1})^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I need your help. I have to prove absolute convergence and conditional convergence to this two series. I have no idea how to do this.

> a) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n (x-1)^{n}}{2^{n} (3n - 1)}$$
>
> b) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n -1}\left(\frac{x+2}{x-1}\right)^{n}    
> $$

I think the b series has something to do with the harmotic series. 
It would be so nice if you could give me some tips or send me a solution.

thank you

Comment: Tip for a): Determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{n}{3n-1}z^n$. Tip for b): Determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1{2n-1}z^n$.

Comment: is it possible to solve this without complex numers?

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem in two:

1. Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac n{3n-1} \, z^n$$
2. Replace $z=\frac {x-1}2$ and you'll be able to determine the values of $x$ where your series converges.

Do the same for your second series, with $z=\frac {x+2}{x-1}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use the ratio test and note that, if the series converges absolutely, then it converges conditionally.